# How to make edge types into categories? Especially how to reindex the df according to G.edges()?

Tags: python, colors, networkx, edges, reindex

I am drawing a graph in networkx.
The nodelist and edgelist are read from csv using pandas.
The columns of edgelist include: 'source', 'target', 'value', like this:
source target value
A       B      1
A       C      2
A       D      3
H       B      1
H       E      2

I need to map colors to each type of the edges.
I tried to apply pd.Categorical() for this procedure. However, it requires the df to be reindexed according to a collection, which I suppose refers to G.edges().
But, when I use edge = edge.reindex(G.edges() ), the edge['value'].cat.codes turns wrong, like this:

A       B      -1
C      -1
D      -1
H       B      -1
E      -1

It seems the duplicated nodes in the source column are lost automatically. And this leads to a missed mapping of colors to the edges.
How to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @lionhead!  Welcome to Stack Overflow! :^) Hope you stick around!  It might be helpful in future questions relating to `pandas` to include data in a format that can by copy-pasted and run.  For instance, you could use `print(df.head().to_dict())` to post a short sample of your data that is runnable.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well for more tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use the `value` column of your dataframe as a categorical variable to color your edges by, I don't think you need to do anything more to the dataframe.  Just pass the `value` column as an edge attribute when building your network.

Then, when you plot, you can color by the list of edge attributes:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap

data = {'source': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'H', 4: 'H'},
        'target': {0: 'B', 1: 'C', 2: 'D', 3: 'B', 4: 'E'},
        'value': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, edge_attr='value')
colors = [d['value'] for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True)]
nx.draw(G, edge_color=colors, edge_cmap=get_cmap('jet'))
```

gives

[image: edge_colored_network_plot]

Comment: Hi! The problem is the nodelist and edgelist are read from csv as two dfs, cos they could become quite long. For the nodelist, I have used these lines to assign colors according to their types:
carac = carac.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
carac = carac.set_index('ID')
carac = carac.reindex(G.nodes())
carac['type'] = pd.Categorical(carac['type'])
carac['type'].cat.codes
Without reindex, the colors and node types miscorrespond.
For the edges, the situation is similar. The carac['value'].cat.codes got "-1", which means there is not a match between df and edgelist.

Comment: I have tried to add a new column combining the two cols ('source' and 'target') for reindex, which looks like: AB, AC, AD, HB, HE. However, the carac['value'].cat.codes still got "-1". As describe in the question: some duplicated nodes are removed automatically.
I have found an alternative solution: nx.draw_networkx_edges () to add the different types of edges. But it seems more 'automatic' if it is possible to apply the same procedure as to the nodes. The question is how to reindex according to two columns in a df?